# Explicit conversion when comparing database values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to select a row in my database by its ID and then select all rows that have a "Position" value higher than the row selected by ID, like this:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
MyDataContext d = new MyDataContext
Item itemID = d.Items.Single(row => row.ID == id);
Item itemPos = d.Items.Select(row => row.Position > itemID.Position);
```

The bottom line is saying that an explicit conversion exists but I can't seem to fix it

Having read the answers so far, the code now looks like this:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
MyDataContext d = new MyDataContext
Item itemID = d.Items.Single(row => row.ID == id);
var itemPos = d.Items.Where(row => row.Position > itemID.Position);
```

But then when I try and edit the Position of selected rows, it seems I am doing that wrong:

```
itemPos.Position = itemPos.Position - 1;
```

I would have expected that line to reduce the current position by 1.
I'm still new to all this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement will return you an `IEnumerable<Item>`, whereas the type you are specifying is for a single `Item`. you may try the following.

```
 var itemPos = d.Items.Where(row => row.Position > itemID.Position);
```

Use [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) for implicit type, or use `IEnumerable<Item>` for explicit type, since you are selecting on the basis of a condition you may use `Where` clause instead of `Select`

Comment: Thanks, will that select all rows with a postion that is higher or just the first one it finds?

Comment: @KarlHumphries, I miss read the question, check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to include the edited code which is still leaving me with a problem

Comment: @KarlHumphries, in your edited question you are trying to access a property `Position` of the item, where as itemPos is a collection, you can't access the property like that, you may select a single item from the collection and then access the property

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Item> itemPos = d.Items.Select(row => row.Position > itemID.Position);
```

but the best way is to use `var`.